# Cual puede ser el error en inserción de arrays a la DB de mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql

Nuevamente, como les comente no soy muy ducto en el tema, aunque he avanzado, "eso pienso".
les molesto nuevamente a pedir el favor y me colaboren en indicarme cual es el ERROR del porque NO me inserta la información en la DB
acá lo que tengo.

//arreglo que llega desde la pagina donde se toman los datos:

> array (size=18)  'fecha_ela' => string '2019-05-31' (length=10) 
>   'registro' => string '1' (length=1)  'gestion' => string 'CP'
>   (length=2)  'objeto_gestion' => string 'cvzxcv' (length=6) 
>   'docu_funcionario' =>  array (size=1)  0 => string '123456789'
>   (length=9)  'funcionario' =>  array (size=1)  0 => string 'MILTON
>   RAMIRO QUINTERO CORTES' (length=29)  'esquema1' =>  array (size=1)  0
>   => string 'SGP' (length=3)  'cargo1' =>  array (size=1)  0 => string 'Profesional Universitario' (length=25)  'email1' =>  array (size=1) 
>   0 => string 'miltonque23@gmail.com ' (length=31)  'documento' => 
>   array (size=1)  0 => string '5934553' (length=7)  'nombres' =>  array
>   (size=1)  0 => string 'MAXIMINO CASTILLO ORTIZ ' (length=25) 
>   'esquema' =>  array (size=1)  0 => string 'undefined' (length=9) 
>   'cargo' =>  array (size=1)  0 => string 'Rector Institucion Educativa
>   Completa ' (length=38)  'direccion' =>  array (size=1)  0 => string
>   'undefined' (length=9)  'telefono' =>  array (size=1)  0 => string
>   'undefined' (length=9)  'email' =>  array (size=1)  0 => string
>   'maximinocastilloortiz@yahoo.es ' (length=31)  'autoriza' => string
>   'SI' (length=2)  'guardar' => string 'Insertar datos' (length=14)

//llamada a la pagina que contiene tanto la función de conexión como la de inserción de datos a la DB:

```
 require_once'../myDBC.php';  $nuevo=new myDBC();
```

//asignación de valores "campos" a variables

```
 if (isset ($_POST['insert'])) 
 { 
     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {        
         $fecha_ela = $_POST['fecha_ela'];      
         $registro = $_POST['registro'];        
         $gestion = $_POST['gestion'];       
         $objeto_gestion = $_POST['objeto_gestion'];        
         $docu_funcionario = $_POST['docu_funcionario'];        
         $funcionario = $_POST['funcionario'];          
         $esquema1 = $_POST['esquema1'];                
         $cargo1 = $_POST['cargo1'];        
         $email1 = $_POST['email1'];            
         $documento = $_POST['documento'];          
         $nombres = $_POST['nombres'];      
         $esquema = $_POST['esquema'];      
         $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];      
         $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];      
         $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];        
         $email = $_POST['email'];          
         $autoriza = $_POST['autoriza']; 
     }
```

//llamado a función para inserción de datos

```
$nuevo->agregar_soli($fecha_ela, $registro, $gestion, $objeto_gestion, $docu_funcionario, $funcionario, $esquema1, $cargo1, $email1, $documento, $nombres, $esquema, $cargo, $direccion, $telefono, $email, $autoriza);
}
```

//función de inserción a la DB

```
public function agregar_soli($fecha_ela, $registro, $gestion, $objeto_gestion, $docu_funcionario, $funcionario, $esquema1, $cargo1, $email1,$documento, $nombres, $esquema, $cargo, $direccion, $telefono, $email, $autoriza)
    {       
        for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['documento']); $i++){              
            if(($_POST['documento'][$i]==''))
            { continue;}                
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (fecha_ela,registro,gestion,objeto_gestion,docu_funcionario,funcionario,esquema1,cargo1,email1) VALUES ('$fecha_ela','$registro','$gestion','$objeto_gestion','$docu_funcionario[$i]','$funcionario[$i]','$esquema1[$i]','$cargo1[$i]','$email1[$i]','$documento[$i]','$nombres[$i]','$esquema[$i]','$cargo[$i]','$direccion[$i]','$telefono[$i]','$email[$i]','$autoriza')";             
            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
            $res = mysql_query($sql);       
        }               
    }
```

Comment: ¿Que error muestra?